# Разбавить строку точками c#

Tags: java, c#, c++

Как на c# реализовать алгоритм что бы разбавить строку как можно большим количеством, но чтобы не было больше двух точек подряд (2 точки подряд тоже нельзя), как и в начале и конце.

Собственно есть строка "stackoverflow", нужно её разбавить точками(подскажите алгоритм), вот пример:

```html
stackoverflo.w@gmail.com
stackoverfl.ow@gmail.com
stackoverfl.o.w@gmail.com
stackoverf.low@gmail.com
stackoverf.lo.w@gmail.com
stackoverf.l.ow@gmail.com
stackoverf.l.o.w@gmail.com
stackover.flow@gmail.com
stackover.flo.w@gmail.com
stackover.fl.ow@gmail.com
stackover.fl.o.w@gmail.com
stackover.f.low@gmail.com
stackover.f.lo.w@gmail.com
stackover.f.l.ow@gmail.com
stackover.f.l.o.w@gmail.com
stackove.rflow@gmail.com
stackove.rflo.w@gmail.com
stackove.rfl.ow@gmail.com
stackove.rfl.o.w@gmail.com
stackove.rf.low@gmail.com
stackove.rf.lo.w@gmail.com
stackove.rf.l.ow@gmail.com
stackove.rf.l.o.w@gmail.com
stackove.r.flow@gmail.com
stackove.r.flo.w@gmail.com
stackove.r.fl.ow@gmail.com
stackove.r.fl.o.w@gmail.com
stackove.r.f.low@gmail.com
stackove.r.f.lo.w@gmail.com
stackove.r.f.l.ow@gmail.com
stackove.r.f.l.o.w@gmail.com
stackov.erflow@gmail.com
stackov.erflo.w@gmail.com
stackov.erfl.ow@gmail.com
stackov.erfl.o.w@gmail.com
stackov.erf.low@gmail.com
stackov.erf.lo.w@gmail.com
stackov.erf.l.ow@gmail.com
stackov.erf.l.o.w@gmail.com
stackov.er.flow@gmail.com
stackov.er.flo.w@gmail.com
stackov.er.fl.ow@gmail.com
stackov.er.fl.o.w@gmail.com
stackov.er.f.low@gmail.com
stackov.er.f.lo.w@gmail.com
stackov.er.f.l.ow@gmail.com
stackov.er.f.l.o.w@gmail.com
stackov.e.rflow@gmail.com
stackov.e.rflo.w@gmail.com
stackov.e.rfl.ow@gmail.com
stackov.e.rfl.o.w@gmail.com
stackov.e.rf.low@gmail.com
stackov.e.rf.lo.w@gmail.com
stackov.e.rf.l.ow@gmail.com
stackov.e.rf.l.o.w@gmail.com
stackov.e.r.flow@gmail.com
stackov.e.r.flo.w@gmail.com
stackov.e.r.fl.ow@gmail.com
stackov.e.r.fl.o.w@gmail.com
stackov.e.r.f.low@gmail.com
stackov.e.r.f.lo.w@gmail.com
stackov.e.r.f.l.ow@gmail.com
stackov.e.r.f.l.o.w@gmail.com
stacko.verflow@gmail.com
stacko.verflo.w@gmail.com
stacko.verfl.ow@gmail.com
stacko.verfl.o.w@gmail.com
stacko.verf.low@gmail.com
stacko.verf.lo.w@gmail.com
stacko.verf.l.ow@gmail.com
stacko.verf.l.o.w@gmail.com
stacko.ver.flow@gmail.com
stacko.ver.flo.w@gmail.com
stacko.ver.fl.ow@gmail.com
stacko.ver.fl.o.w@gmail.com
stacko.ver.f.low@gmail.com
stacko.ver.f.lo.w@gmail.com
stacko.ver.f.l.ow@gmail.com
stacko.ver.f.l.o.w@gmail.com
stacko.ve.rflow@gmail.com
stacko.ve.rflo.w@gmail.com
stacko.ve.rfl.ow@gmail.com
stacko.ve.rfl.o.w@gmail.com
stacko.ve.rf.low@gmail.com
stacko.ve.rf.lo.w@gmail.com
stacko.ve.rf.l.ow@gmail.com
stacko.ve.rf.l.o.w@gmail.com
stacko.ve.r.flow@gmail.com
stacko.ve.r.flo.w@gmail.com
stacko.ve.r.fl.ow@gmail.com
stacko.ve.r.fl.o.w@gmail.com
stacko.ve.r.f.low@gmail.com
stacko.ve.r.f.lo.w@gmail.com
stacko.ve.r.f.l.ow@gmail.com
stacko.ve.r.f.l.o.w@gmail.com
stacko.v.erflow@gmail.com
stacko.v.erflo.w@gmail.com
stacko.v.erfl.ow@gmail.com
stacko.v.erfl.o.w@gmail.com
stacko.v.erf.low@gmail.com
stacko.v.erf.lo.w@gmail.com
stacko.v.erf.l.ow@gmail.com
stacko.v.erf.l.o.w@gmail.com
stacko.v.er.flow@gmail.com
stacko.v.er.flo.w@gmail.com
stacko.v.er.fl.ow@gmail.com
stacko.v.er.fl.o.w@gmail.com
stacko.v.er.f.low@gmail.com
stacko.v.er.f.lo.w@gmail.com
stacko.v.er.f.l.ow@gmail.com
stacko.v.er.f.l.o.w@gmail.com
stacko.v.e.rflow@gmail.com
stacko.v.e.rflo.w@gmail.com
stacko.v.e.rfl.ow@gmail.com
stacko.v.e.rfl.o.w@gmail.com
stacko.v.e.rf.low@gmail.com
stacko.v.e.rf.lo.w@gmail.com
stacko.v.e.rf.l.ow@gmail.com
stacko.v.e.rf.l.o.w@gmail.com
stacko.v.e.r.flow@gmail.com
stacko.v.e.r.flo.w@gmail.com
stacko.v.e.r.fl.ow@gmail.com
stacko.v.e.r.fl.o.w@gmail.com
stacko.v.e.r.f.low@gmail.com
stacko.v.e.r.f.lo.w@gmail.com
stacko.v.e.r.f.l.ow@gmail.com
stacko.v.e.r.f.l.o.w@gmail.com
stack.overflow@gmail.com
stack.overflo.w@gmail.com
stack.overfl.ow@gmail.com
stack.overfl.o.w@gmail.com
stack.overf.low@gmail.com
stack.overf.lo.w@gmail.com
stack.overf.l.ow@gmail.com
stack.overf.l.o.w@gmail.com
stack.over.flow@gmail.com
stack.over.flo.w@gmail.com
stack.over.fl.ow@gmail.com
stack.over.fl.o.w@gmail.com
stack.over.f.low@gmail.com
stack.over.f.lo.w@gmail.com
stack.over.f.l.ow@gmail.com
stack.over.f.l.o.w@gmail.com
stack.ove.rflow@gmail.com
stack.ove.rflo.w@gmail.com
stack.ove.rfl.ow@gmail.com
stack.ove.rfl.o.w@gmail.com
stack.ove.rf.low@gmail.com
stack.ove.rf.lo.w@gmail.com
stack.ove.rf.l.ow@gmail.com
stack.ove.rf.l.o.w@gmail.com
stack.ove.r.flow@gmail.com
stack.ove.r.flo.w@gmail.com
stack.ove.r.fl.ow@gmail.com
stack.ove.r.fl.o.w@gmail.com
stack.ove.r.f.low@gmail.com
stack.ove.r.f.lo.w@gmail.com
stack.ove.r.f.l.ow@gmail.com
stack.ove.r.f.l.o.w@gmail.com
stack.ov.erflow@gmail.com
stack.ov.erflo.w@gmail.com
stack.ov.erfl.ow@gmail.com
stack.ov.erfl.o.w@gmail.com
stack.ov.erf.low@gmail.com
stack.ov.erf.lo.w@gmail.com
stack.ov.erf.l.ow@gmail.com
stack.ov.erf.l.o.w@gmail.com
stack.ov.er.flow@gmail.com
stack.ov.er.flo.w@gmail.com
stack.ov.er.fl.ow@gmail.com
stack.ov.er.fl.o.w@gmail.com
stack.ov.er.f.low@gmail.com
stack.ov.er.f.lo.w@gmail.com
stack.ov.er.f.l.ow@gmail.com
stack.ov.er.f.l.o.w@gmail.com
stack.ov.e.rflow@gmail.com
stack.ov.e.rflo.w@gmail.com
stack.ov.e.rfl.ow@gmail.com
stack.ov.e.rfl.o.w@gmail.com
stack.ov.e.rf.low@gmail.com
stack.ov.e.rf.lo.w@gmail.com
stack.ov.e.rf.l.ow@gmail.com
stack.ov.e.rf.l.o.w@gmail.com
stack.ov.e.r.flow@gmail.com
stack.ov.e.r.flo.w@gmail.com
stack.ov.e.r.fl.ow@gmail.com
stack.ov.e.r.fl.o.w@gmail.com
stack.ov.e.r.f.low@gmail.com
stack.ov.e.r.f.lo.w@gmail.com
stack.ov.e.r.f.l.ow@gmail.com
stack.ov.e.r.f.l.o.w@gmail.com
stack.o.verflow@gmail.com
stack.o.verflo.w@gmail.com
stack.o.verfl.ow@gmail.com
stack.o.verfl.o.w@gmail.com
stack.o.verf.low@gmail.com
stack.o.verf.lo.w@gmail.com
stack.o.verf.l.ow@gmail.com
stack.o.verf.l.o.w@gmail.com
stack.o.ver.flow@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Между каждой парой букв - таких мест у вас 12 - либо точка есть, либо нет. Если есть - обозначим как 1, если нет - как 0. Получается строка из 12 нулей и единиц, т.е. просто бинарное представление числа от 0 до 4095...

Дальше рассказывать или уже все очевидно? :)

**Update**

Гм, как ни грустно - но таки рассказывать... :(

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const char * s = "stackoverflow";


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(unsigned int n = 0; n < 4096; ++n)
    {
        cout << s[0];
        unsigned int m = n;
        for(int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
        {
            if (m&1) cout << ".";
            m >>= 1;
            cout << s[i+1];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Я то понял это, но как реализовать в коде ума не приложу, сижу уже часа два, и ничего не выходит(

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < 4096; ++i)`  :) А в цикле - уж смотрите, что в конкретном месте, нолик или единичка...

Comment: А если это будет другое слово, и другой длинны?

Comment: @Monolith, если небольшой длины, то `for (int i = 0; i < (1 << word.length()); ++i) ...`

Comment: @diraria, и а цикле что делать, не могу никак понять, можно полный ответ?

Comment: @diraria, а если `word.length() > 31`? :)

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, использовать `long long`

Comment: Ну ладно, см. дополненный ответ...

Comment: @Monolith то есть вы два часа просидели, но код сам собой не написался?

Answer (score 2):

Рассмотрим строку:

```
hello
```

В ней есть `длина_строки - 1` мест, куда можно вставить точку:

```
h.e.l.l.o
```

В каждое место можно либо вставить точку, либо не вставить. Пусть мы вставили точки в некоторые позиции:

```
h.e.ll.o
```

Сопоставим каждой позиции 0 (если мы не вставили в эту позицию точку) или  1 (если вставили):

```
h.e.l l.o
 1 1 0 1
```

Получим строку из нулей и единиц:

```
1101
```

По сути это число от `0` до `(длина_слова - 1) ^ 2 - 1`, записанное в двоичной системе исчисления. Переберём все такие числа:

```
for (int mask = 0; mask < (1 << (длина_слова - 1)); ++mask)
```

и для каждого числа найдём строку, ему соответствующую:

```
string result;
for (int i = 0; i < длина_слова - 1; ++i) {
    result.push_back(word[i]);
    if (mask & (1 << i))
        result.push_back('.');
}
result.push_back(word.back());
```

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/tliQII)

Comment: Диапазон маски в два раза меньше надо сделать

Comment: @alexolut, да, точно, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Это обычный перебор. Создаете цикл от 0 до требуемого 2^(n+1) и в тех местах, где бит равен единице, там вставляем точку. Ну так же необходимо проверять, нет ли в этих числах спаренных единиц.

Как это будет выглядеть в двоичном виде:

```
1 - 0001
2 - 0010
3 - 0011 (отбрасываем)
4 - 0100
5 - ...
```

Ну вот пример кода (правда на С++, ну думаю это не проблема) :

```
bool check(int num, int length)
{
    if ((1 << length)&num) return false;
    if (1&num) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < length-1; i++)
    {
        if ( (1 << i) & num  && (1 << (i + 1)) & num) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    string s = "stackoverflow";
    int length = s.length();
    for (int mask = 0; mask < (1 << 2*length); mask++)
    {
        if (!check(mask,length)) continue;
        string copy = s;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (mask & (1 << i)) copy.insert(copy.begin()+i,'.');
        }
        cout << copy <<endl;
    }
}
```

Часть вывода:

```
sta.cko.v.erflow
s.t.ack.o.verflow
stac.ko.v.erflow
s.ta.ck.o.verflow
st.a.ck.o.verflow
stack.o.v.erflow
s.tac.k.o.verflow
st.ac.k.o.verflow
sta.c.k.o.verflow
s.t.a.c.k.overflow
stackoverf.low
s.tackover.flow
st.ackover.flow
sta.ckover.flow
s.t.ackove.rflow
stac.kover.flow
s.ta.ckove.rflow
st.a.ckove.rflow
```

Comment: Нужно что бы первый и последний символ не был точкой, и точки вставлялись, а не заменяли существующие символы

Comment: Невнимательно прочитал условие, исправил