# Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "int" в "bool" в контексте оператора if на C#

Tags: c#

Собственно есть код написанный на c++, в нем происходит побитовое сравнение, но данный код не работает на c#, хотя синтаксис почти идентичный. Нужно перевести кусок кода с c++ на c#

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const char * s = "stackoverflow";


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(unsigned int n = 0; n < 4096; ++n)
    {
        cout << s[0];
        unsigned int m = n;
        for(int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
        {
            if (m&1) cout << ".";
            m >>= 1;
            cout << s[i+1];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

не компилируется из-за `if (m&1)`, ошибка Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "int" в "bool".

```
string testWord = "stackoverflow";
for (int n = 0; n < 4096; ++n)
{
    string buff = "";
    buff += testWord[0];
    int m = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
    {
        if (m & 1) buff += ".";
        m >>= 1;
        buff += testWord[i + 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: А что делает этот участок кода?

Comment: @Byulent, [вот что он делает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/724015/227016)...

Comment: Вспомните, при каких условиях выражение трактуется как true внутри `if` в C++, и при каких в C#. Всё сразу станет понятно.

Comment: @VladD, а можно менее завуалированный ответ, больше конкретики?

Comment: @Monolith: Ну, подумайте, почему упрощённый вариант `if (m)` компилируется в C++ и не компилируется в C#.

Comment: @VladD, не имею ни малейшего предположения, может вы мне подскажете?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В C++ в контексте `if` может встречаться выражение не только типа `bool`, но и числового типа (а также указатель). При этом нулевое значение трактуется как `false`, а ненулевое — как `true`.

Это приводило к различным неприятностям,* да и просто было несемантично. Поэтому в C# от этого отказались, и внутри `if` разрешены лишь булевы выражения**.

Для кодирования условия с числом в C# вспомним, что результат в C++ считался равным `true` тогда и только тогда, когда число было ненулевым. Значит, и кодировать C++-код `if (p)` для числового `p` на C# нужно в виде `if (p != 0)`.

Для вашего случая — `if ((m & 1) != 0)`.

---

*Классический пример — пропущенный второй символ `=` в сравнении вида `if (a == 5)` спокойно компилировался, т. к. `a = 5` — числовое выражение, имеющее значение 5. (В качестве «лекарства» приходится подставлять различные костыли, вроде уродливых «условий Йоды».)

**Или выражения, неявно конвертирующиеся в `bool`. Или выражения типов, для которых определены [операторы `true`/`false`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/true-operator).

Comment: Занимательно. А почему `true` и `false` отдельные операторы, а не как в С++, приведение к `bool`? Если это долгая история, можно не отвечать :)

Comment: попрошу Йоду не оскорблять!

Comment: @D-side потому что корректного приведения к bool может вовсе не существовать, например в троичной логике. По ссылке на документацию как раз пример такой логики.

Comment: @Anatol: Йоду джедаев магистра оскорбить в мыслях не имел вовсе я; паттерн же, условиями Йоды именуемый, тем не менее для глаз землян отвратен зело есть.